# Codeigniter Query Chaining

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on a query in Codeigniter and I'm trying to keep it clean looking. I haven't even added most of the fields yet and I can see it getting unwieldy, particularly with the select_sum's.

Is there a cleaner way of writing them or a way to combine them?

```
$this->db->select('Map');
$this->db->select_sum('Kills')->select_sum('Deaths')->select_sum('Win')->select_sum('Loss')->select_sum('Win + Loss', 'GP');
$this->db->from('games');
$this->db->where('Name', $player_name);
$this->db->join('players', 'players.PlayerID = games.PlayerID');
$this->db->join('gameinfo', 'games.GameID = gameinfo.GameID');
$this->db->group_by('Map'); 
$this->db->order_by('Kills', "desc"); 
$this->db->limit(10);

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw SQL is my suggestion.

```
$name = $this->db->escape($player_name);

$sql = "
    SELECT Map, SUM(Kills), SUM(Deaths), SUM(Win), SUM(Loss), SUM(Win + Loss) AS GP
    FROM games
    JOIN players ON (players.PlayerID = games.PlayerID)
    JOIN gameinfo ON (games.GameID = gameinfo.GameID)
    WHERE Name = $name
    GROUP BY Map
    ORDER BY Kills DESC
    LIMIT 10
";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);

return $query->result_array();
```

In my opinion, if only we can make a pretty indentation, it is much more readable than the CI active record version.

Comment: And what about dinamically created queries? In this case comfortable to use CI's AR.

Comment: Yes, sure. It all depends. I have nothing against using CI's AR. I do use it! It has many benefits, for sure. It's only a matter of, **sometimes**, being easier to write and to read a query in pure SQL than making the transformations in your head or having to call `$this->db->last_query()` to discover what the AR built final query looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm use similar like this:

```
$this->db->select("map_name")
     ->from("maptables")
     ->where("maptables.id",2);
```

For me it's readable :)

(I've made an own library which does similar like AR - because AR has some bugs)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it in this way in my opinion this is more readable

```
 $this->db->select('Map, SUM(Kills), SUM(Deaths), SUM(Win), SUM(Loss), SUM(Win + Loss, GP)');
 $this->db->from('games');<br />
 $this->db->where('Name', $player_name);<br />
 $this->db->join('players', 'players.PlayerID = games.PlayerID');<br />
 $this->db->join('gameinfo', 'games.GameID = gameinfo.GameID');<br />
 $this->db->group_by('Map');<br />
 $this->db->order_by('Kills', "desc");<br />
 $this->db->limit(10);<br />

 $query = $this->db->get();

 return $query->result_array();`
```